# Printing values in row order from dictionary/ list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, encode

Could someone show me how to get the values from a dictionary in row order (STARTING FROM SECOND ROW) e.g. get the first value from all rows, when rows finish, move onto getting the second value from all rows until all the values have been collected (when no more columns).

E.g. here is a table:

```
('E', 'K', 'Y') # <- don't get the values from the first row
('B', 'C', 'B') # start getting values from this (second row)
('C', 'B', 'F')
('F', 'C', 'A')
('C', 'C', 'C')
('B', 'C', 'B')
('E', 'B', 'F')
('B', 'B', 'F')
('D', 'A', 'A')  
('A', 'D', 'F')
```

The table above should print the values:

```
BCFCBEBDACBCCCBBADBFACBFFAF
```

Creating an encode and decoder program. stuck with printing values in correct order.

Thanks.

Comment: Post actual data-structures. There's no dictionary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterantive way, that gets a list of characters instead of str:

```
print([v for r in (row for row in zip(*l[1:])) for v in r])  
#['B', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'A', 'F']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the tuples in a list you can use `zip` and `join` :

```
>>> l=[('E', 'K', 'Y') ,('B', 'C', 'B') ,('C', 'B', 'F'),('F', 'C', 'A'),('C', 'C', 'C'),('B', 'C', 'B'),('E', 'B', 'F'),('B', 'B', 'F'),('D', 'A', 'A')]
>>> ''.join([''.join(i) for i in zip(*l[1:])])
'BCFCBEBDCBCCCBBABFACBFFA'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data structure is a list of tuples, meaning:

```
l =[('C', 'B', 'F'),
    ('F', 'C', 'A'),
    ('C', 'C', 'C'),
    ('B', 'C', 'B'),
    ('E', 'B', 'F'),
    ('B', 'B', 'F'),
    ('D', 'A', 'A'), 
    ('A', 'D', 'F')]
```

Something like this could solve the problem:

```
string = ""
for i in range(3):
    for element in range(1, len(l)):
        string+=l[element][i]
```